# 'GBTClassificationModel' object has no attribute 'fitMultiple' - pyspark

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Encountered the following error message while trying to do cross-validation on GBT. I had no issues running the GBT model previously.

Is fitMultiple no longer supported? I am using PySpark 2.4.4 by the way.

This is my code:

```
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(gbt.maxDepth, [2, 4, 6]).addGrid(gbt.maxBins, [20, 60]).addGrid(gbt.maxIter, [10, 20]).build()
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=gbt, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid, evaluator=evaluator)

# Run cross validations.  This can take about 6 minutes since it is training over 20 trees!
cvModel = cv.fit(train)
predictions = cvModel.transform(test)
evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
```

This is the error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-95e5a7d270fe> in <module>
      6 
      7 # Run cross validations.  This can take about 6 minutes since it is training over 20 trees!
----> 8 cvModel = cv.fit(train)
      9 predictions = cvModel.transform(test)
     10 evaluator.evaluate(predictions)

/anaconda_env/personal/gleow/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/anaconda_env/personal/gleow/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    301             train = df.filter(~condition).cache()
    302 
--> 303             tasks = _parallelFitTasks(est, train, eva, validation, epm, collectSubModelsParam)
    304             for j, metric, subModel in pool.imap_unordered(lambda f: f(), tasks):
    305                 metrics[j] += (metric / nFolds)

/anaconda_env/personal/gleow/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in _parallelFitTasks(est, train, eva, validation, epm, collectSubModel)
     47     :return: (int, float, subModel), an index into `epm` and the associated metric value.
     48     """
---> 49     modelIter = est.fitMultiple(train, epm)
     50 
     51     def singleTask():

AttributeError: 'GBTClassificationModel' object has no attribute 'fitMultiple'
```

Comment: You are talking for GBT, while your code shows random forest - please edit accordingly

Comment: Edited. I wanted to try it out with randomforest but it did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooted my codes and found the bug... turns out that I had initialized gbt and fitted in the following:

```
gbt = GBTClassifier(maxIter=10)
gbt = gbt.fit(train)
...
...
```

So in trying to run the following:

```
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator

paramGrid = ...
evaluator = ...
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=gbt, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid, evaluator=evaluator)
```

The CrossValidator is actually calling 'gbt.fit(train)' which is not the classifier object anymore. So what I did was to initialize gbt = GBTClassifier(maxIter=10) again.